# Laravel 5.4 Argument 3 passed to Collective must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory, string given

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I've installed the Kris Form Builder on Laravel 5.4 from:
https://github.com/kristijanhusak/laravel-form-builder/

when I want to render the form in the blade I got this error:

```
Argument 3 passed to Collective\Html\FormBuilder::__construct() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory, string given, called in /Applications/vendor/kris/laravel-form-builder/src/Kris/LaravelFormBuilder/FormBuilderServiceProvider.php on line 86 and defined (View: /Applications/resources/views/entity-items.blade.php)
```

**Update:**
I've solved the problem myself!
in according to this tutorial : http://kristijanhusak.github.io/laravel-form-builder/overview/installation.html

you should also add `http://kristijanhusak.github.io/laravel-form-builder/overview/installation.html`

and `'Former'       => Former\Facades\Former::class,`
in **config\app.php**

Comment: show your controller code

Comment: `$form = $formBuilder->create('App\Forms\SongForm', [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'url' => route('entity_items.store')
        ]);

        return view('entity-items', compact('form'));`

Comment: whole method, with dependency injection.

Comment: `public function index(FormBuilder $formBuilder)
    {


        $form = $formBuilder->create('App\Forms\SongForm', [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'url' => route('entity_items.store')
        ]);

        return view('entity-items', compact('form'));

    }`

Comment: u have to change your `use Collective\Html\FormBuilder;`  to `use Kris\LaravelFormBuilder\FormBuilder;` as your error shows, you're trying to import wrong class.

Comment: I've already used `use Kris\LaravelFormBuilder\FormBuilder;`!!!

Comment: I've solved myself it and updated the question!